# cleraInterval ()not working when on a component that contains useEffect to call the API (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**how to stop setInterval on on the component that contains the APi call** ??

example case

```
.....

useEffect(() => {
  getDataFromApi()
})


let count = 0;
let interval = setInterval(function(){

    // increasing the count by 1
    count += 1;

    // when count equals to 5, stop the function
    if(count === 5){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    // display count
    console.log(count);

}, 2000);
```

but in case program not stop when after five times

Answer (score 0):

if you are attempting to only run the effect once on mount, then you need to add the second param to the `useEffect` function to do that.

```
// by putting this logic in the useEffect, you are creating a clousure that will prevent interval from being mutated on every render.
useEffect(() => {
  getDataFromApi()


  let count = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(function(){

  // increasing the count by 1
  count += 1;

  // when count equals to 5, stop the function
  if(count === 5){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  // display count
  console.log(count);

  }, 2000);
}, [])
```

the reason the code doesn't stop is because the component is mutating the reference to the original `interval` everytime the component rerenders.  For this reason, you really shouldn't use a setInterval in a component render method.

Comment: I use setInterval to check the status of the API for automatic screen switching, and in useEffect I have added a second param but clearInterval doesn't work in realtime

Comment: when the screen is changed, setInterval still works. and clearInterval() not working

Comment: yeah, its not 100% gonna fix, if you have something else up the chain that is causing rerender, you should explore Async/Await or `Promise` in js

Comment: i updated the code to fix it, again, this is not really a good way of implementing it, but its a way to use closures in js to fix what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by creating a interval variable first and clearActiveInterval function like this

```
let count = 0;
let interval = null;

function clearActiveInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

rest of you code implementation would be like this

```
interval = setInterval(function () {
  // increasing the count by 1
  count += 1;

  // when count equals to 5, stop the function
  if (count === 5) {
    clearActiveInterval();
  }

  // display count
  console.log(count);
}, 2000);
```